# How to automatically shutdown *any* idle EC2 instances automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to build something that will automatically shutdown *any* idle EC2 instances. I looked up online and the CloudWatch solution only works on a per-instance level, meaning you have to add one for each instance manually. But is there a way that I could set up something that automatically shutdowns *any* idle EC2 instances?

Comment: https://nubisnovem.com/amazon-aws-ec2-instance-automatic-shutdown-by-idle-cpu/

Comment: @DrZoo still this is on one instance instead of any/all instances. Any idea on how to do so for all instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way I can think of is to build a Lambda which will fetch the cloudwatch metrics and then terminate the instances if below certain CPU%.